# Web Component - Auto Complete Checklist Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Anybody can lead me to a resource that covers having an autocomplete checklist box. This would respond to the user typing something in the search field, and then there are suggestions from which the user can choose (by clicking the check boxes next to the possible results).

Comment: Not seen anything out in the wild, but sounds pretty straight-forward to build.